# refresh fragment that gone to activity after back pressed in that activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, refresh

I have a fragment in a tabbed activity.It redirects from onclicklistener to an activity.After changes made in that activity.User will press back button.So in my fragment i need a listener that is fired after come back from that activity.Or maybe after user made the changes I give user a button to go back to that fragment and reload the fragment meanwhile.I don't know either way.
i tried onResume() onStart() on every thing didn't work because nothing happened to fragment in that transaction.
I tried addOnBackStackChangedListener() but it should be placed in the activity not fragment.
so i don't know what to do?
thanks for your time

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
        getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
                new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBackStackChanged() {
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(getTargetFragment()).attach(getTargetFragment()).commit();
                    }
                });
        //TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        //textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onResume();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have two two activities A and B.Initially Fragment f1 is added to A.When you click on item in f1 start activity B with startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode) and in onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  either update the fragment data(if possible) or reload the fragment.

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem for a list view after user made an item as favorite and press back button i hope it work for you:

When you open an activity inside a fragment it will go on Pause and when you press Back button the onResume will be executed so I called my method once more in onResume method like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() { 
    super.onResume();
    storedfavoritesitem = FavoriteModel.getAllFavorites(); 
    if (storedfavoritesitem.size() == 0) {
        nolist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        nolist.setText("Tu Lista de Favoritos está vacía ;)");
    }
    if (adapter!=null && currentLocation!=null) {
        mResualt.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < storedfavoritesitem.size(); i++) {
            FavoriteModel Faveitem = storedfavoritesitem.get(i);
            String locality = Faveitem.name;
            String cityname = Faveitem.city;
            int id = Faveitem.id;
            double lat = Faveitem.lat;
            double lon = Faveitem.lon;
            Location location = new Location("Beach");
            location.setLatitude(lat);
            location.setLongitude(lon);
            float distance = currentLocation.distanceTo(location);
            mResualt.add(new SearchResualtClass(id, distance / 1000, locality, cityname));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

cheers!